# Cannot connect to internet within XP virtual Image (Vhd file)

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have been using VirtualBox to boot into my XP image. I am using cable broadband (via LAN).  I can browse the internet in my host but not in my virtual machine.

Comment: What mode of networking are you using on VirtualBox?

Comment: What type of virtual connector is your virtual machine using (ie, bridged, NAT)? Does the virtual machine receive a valid IP address

Comment: hi Matt, i have test all (NAT, Bridged adapter, Internal Network, Host -only adapter) nothing works

Comment: I have used both but not able to access internet, second, the valid IP address: IP address is given by the service provider (a Static one) and we have to manually configure it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try:

1. Set the networking type to **Bridged Mode** paying attention to which network card it is bridged with.
2. Make sure the latest version of the VirtualBox guest additions are installed.
3. Check the network settings in the guest OS to confirm that:

   - The network card is detected and configured
   - A valid IP address has been provided by your router
4. You can communicate between the host computer and the guest operating system (ping)

Comment: i have a doubt, the IP adress is actually a static one which was given by the network provider, we (users) will configure this IP manually (LAN), now i usually do not have an another IP bcs only one IP can be given to a connection, so i have used the same in the virtual machine, is this approach is wrong? guess we can't use same IP on host and on VM? If, so is there any way to solve my problem (like sharing the internet b/w host and VM)

Comment: Ah, so you have cable modem linked direct to PC?  In that case you will need to use __NAT__ mode and the VirtualBox built-in DHCP server.  Set your guest OS to obtain an IP automatically.

Comment: you are great!!!!!!!!!!!! it works. Thanks a lot